C++ Mongo Interface : Version-2 Authentication
Refactored part of the original code:
c++ Mongo Interface
In the original code I had put the authentication in the constructor of the socket stream. This made it hard to unit test. So I have refactored this code into into its own authentication class into which you pass the stream. The authentication code then uses the stream to authenticate with the server.
I have split out the specific implementation I am using ScramSha. This is because Mongo can use multiple authentication mechanisms and part of the handshake is to indicate what authentication is available. The main authentication code sees what the server wants to use and what is available locally. The local application can register methods it is willing to use (I have only implemented one method ScramSha but others can be implemented.
P.S. If anybody is familiar with SSH authentication and has some pointers I would love to get some input.
Authenticate.h
  #ifndef THORSANVIL_DB_MONGO_AUTHENTICATE_H
  #define THORSANVIL_DB_MONGO_AUTHENTICATE_H

  // https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/mongodb-handshake/handshake.rst

  #include "ThorsMongoConfig.h"
  #include "MongoUtil.h"

  #include "ThorSerialize/MongoUtility.h"

  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <optional>

  namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
  {

  namespace Auth
  {

  /* The following classes are needed as part of the handshake.
   * They describe the local application to the Mongo server.
   *
   * These classes don't do any work (i.e. they are property bags)
   * so they are implemented as "struct" not "class".
   *
   *  Driver:
   *  OS
   *  Application
   *  Client
   *
   * This class provides information about the Mongo server.
   *
   *  Version
   *
   * Useful classes for Mongo
   *
   *  ObjecID
   *  UTCDateTime
   *
   *
   *  Handshake: This is the command sent to Mongo to initiate authentication.
   *             The response indicates authentication methods available.
   *
   *  Authenticator:  Defines the shape of the authenticator routes (like AuthenticatorScramSha)
   *  Authenticate:   A class that holds registered "Authenticator" functions.
   *                  The "authenticate()" method does the hand shake then uses an appropriate
   *                  authenticator to finish the job.
   *
   */
  struct Driver
  {
      std::string     name;
      std::string     version;

      Driver();
  };

  struct OS
  {
      std::string                 type;
      std::optional<std::string>  name;
      std::optional<std::string>  architecture;
      std::optional<std::string>  version;

      OS();
  };

  struct Application
  {
      std::string     name;

      Application(std::string const& application);
  };

  struct Client
  {
      Application                 application;
      Driver                      driver;
      OS                          os;
      std::optional<std::string>  platform;

      Client(std::string const& application, std::optional<std::string> const& platform);
  };

  struct HandShake
  {
      using Compression = std::vector<std::string>;

      friend ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<HandShake>;
      int             hello;
      std::string     saslSupportedMechs;
      std::string     $db;
      std::string     hostInfo;
      Client          client;
      Compression     compression;

      public:
          HandShake(std::string const& user, std::string const& db, std::string const& application, std::optional<std::string> const& platform, std::vector<std::string> const& compression =
  };

  using ObjectID      = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::MongoUtility::ObjectID;
  using UTCDateTime   = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::MongoUtility::UTCDateTime;

  struct Version
  {
      ObjectID            processId;                          // Seen
      std::int64_t        counter;                            // Seen
  };

  struct HandShakeReply: public CmdReplyBase
  {
      using UserData = void;

      Version         topologyVersion;                        // Seen
      UTCDateTime     localTime;                              // Seen
      std::int32_t    maxBsonObjectSize;                      // Seen
      std::int32_t    maxMessageSizeBytes;                    // Seen
      std::int32_t    maxWriteBatchSize;                      // Seen
      std::int32_t    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes;           // Seen
      std::int32_t    connectionId;                           // Seen
      std::int32_t    minWireVersion;                         // Seen
      std::int32_t    maxWireVersion;                         // Seen
      bool            ismaster;
      bool            readOnly;                               // Seen
      bool            isWritablePrimary;                      // Seen
      std::vector<std::string>    saslSupportedMechs;         // Seen
      std::vector<std::string>    compression;
  };

  }

  using Authenticator = std::function<void(std::iostream&, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)>;
  using AuthMap = std::map<std::string, Authenticator>;

  class Authenticate
  {
      private:
          AuthMap     authenticators;
      public:
          template<typename F>
          void addAuthenticator(std::string const& name, F&& auth)    {authenticators[name] = std::move(auth);}

          void authenticte(std::iostream& stream,
                           std::string const& username,
                           std::string const& password,
                           std::string const& database,
                           std::string const& appName,
                           bool useSnappyCompression);
      private:
         void authenticteHandShake(std::iostream& stream,
                                    std::string const& username,
                                    std::string const& password,
                                    std::string const& database,
                                    std::string const& appName,
                                    std::vector<std::string> const& compression);
  };

  }

  // Simple Triats classes to serialize objects into BSON.
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::Driver,             name, version);
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::OS,                 type, name, architecture, version);
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::Application,        name);
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::Client,             application, driver, os);
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::HandShake,          hello, saslSupportedMechs, $db, hostInfo, client, compression);
  ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::Version,            processId, counter);
  ThorsAnvil_ExpandTrait(ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::CmdReplyBase,
                       ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::HandShakeReply,     topologyVersion, localTime, maxBsonObjectSize, maxMessageSizeBytes, maxWriteBatchSize, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes, c

  #endif

Authenticate.cpp
  #include "Authenticate.h"
  #include "ConnectionBufferMongo.h"
  #include "Op_Msg.h"

  #if !defined(__WINNT__)
  #include <sys/utsname.h>
  #endif

  using namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo;

  Auth::Driver::Driver()
      : name("ThorsAnvil::Mongo::Driver")
      , version("v2.0")
  {}

  Auth::OS::OS()
  {
  #ifdef __WINNT__
      // TODO This is wrong figure out correct values.
      // Fix: test/HandShakeTest.cpp: TEST(HandShakeTest, CreateOS) Currently  Line 83
      type         = "MSYS_NT";       // uname -s | awk -F- '{print $1}'
      name         = "Msys";          // unmae -o
      architecture = "x86_64";        // uname -m
      version      = "3.4.7.x86_64";  // uname -r
  #else
      using UtsName = struct utsname;
      UtsName  buffer;
      int result = uname(&buffer);
      if (result != 0)
      {
          type = "unknown";
          return;
      }
      type         = buffer.sysname;
      architecture = buffer.machine;
      version      = buffer.release;
  #if defined(__APPLE__)
      FILE* fp = popen("sw_vers -productName", "r");
  #elif defined(__linux__)
      FILE* fp = popen("lsb_release -a", "r");
  #endif
      if (fp == nullptr)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowFatal("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::OS", "OS", "Can not get OS Information");
      }
      char pBuffer[100];
      std::string nameBuilder;
      while (fgets(pBuffer, sizeof(pBuffer), fp) != NULL)
      {
  #if defined(__APPLE__)

          nameBuilder += pBuffer;
  #elif defined(__linux__)
          char pValue[100];
          if (sscanf(pBuffer, " Distributor ID: %s", pValue) == 1)
          {
              nameBuilder = pValue;
          }
  #endif
      }
      if (nameBuilder[nameBuilder.size() -1] == '\n')
      {
          nameBuilder.resize(nameBuilder.size() -1);
      }
      name = nameBuilder;
  #endif

      if (name && name.value() == "") {
          name.reset();
      }
      if (architecture && architecture.value() == "") {
          architecture.reset();
      }
      if (version && version.value() == "") {
          version.reset();
      }
  }

  Auth::Application::Application(std::string const& application)
      : name(application)
  {}

  Auth::Client::Client(std::string const& application, std::optional<std::string> const& platformInfo)
      : application(application)
      , platform(platformInfo)
  {
      if (platform && platform.value() == "") {
          platform.reset();
      }
  }

  Auth::HandShake::HandShake(std::string const& username, std::string const& db, std::string const& application, std::optional<std::string> const& platform, std::vector<std::string> const& c
      //: isMaster(true)
      : hello(1)
      , saslSupportedMechs(db + "." + username)
      , $db(db)
      // TODO What should this be?
      , hostInfo("BatCave.local:27017")
      , client(application, platform)
      , compression(compression)
  {}

  void Authenticate::authenticte(std::iostream& stream,
                                 std::string const& username,
                                 std::string const& password,
                                 std::string const& database,
                                 std::string const& appName,
                                 bool useSnappyCompression)
  {
      using std::string_literals::operator""s;

      try
      {
          // Set up what compression algorithms we support.
          std::vector<std::string>    compression;
          if (useSnappyCompression) {
              compression.emplace_back("snappy");
          }
          authenticteHandShake(stream, username, password, database, appName, compression);
      }
      catch (...)
      {
          // If there is an exception.
          // Make sure the stream is in a bad state.
          stream.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

          // Still re-throw as without authentication.
          // We want to force application exit unless explicitly caught.
          throw;
      }
  }

  void Authenticate::authenticteHandShake(
                                 std::iostream& stream,
                                 std::string const& username,
                                 std::string const& password,
                                 std::string const& database,
                                 std::string const& appName,
                                 std::vector<std::string> const& compression)
  {
      // Send handshake
      MessageId               handShakeId;
      Auth::HandShakeReply    reply;
      bool                    handShakeOK = false;

      if (stream << Op_Msg(Auth::HandShake{username, database, appName, {}, compression}, handShakeId))
      {
          if (stream >> Op_Msg(reply, handShakeId)) {
              handShakeOK = true;
          }
      }

      // Check the handshake worked.
      if (!handShakeOK)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Authenticate",
                                   "authenticteHandShake",
                                   "Handshake request or response failed");
      }
      if (reply.ok != 1)
      {
          stream.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Authenticate",
                                   "authenticteHandShake",
                                   "Handshake Request Failed: ",
                                   "Code: ", reply.codeName,
                                   "Msg:  ", reply.errmsg);
      }

      /*
       * Will receive only compression methods that we mentioned we could support
       * in the initial handshake.
       *
       * If we start supporting more compression techniques we need to update this.
       */
      auto find = std::find(std::begin(reply.compression), std::end(reply.compression), "snappy");
      if (find != std::end(reply.compression))
      {
          ConnectionBufferMongo* buffer = dynamic_cast<ConnectionBufferMongo*>(stream.rdbuf());
          if (buffer) {
              buffer->setCompressionOnWrite();
          }
      }

      // Check the authentication mechanisms supported by the server.
      bool authenticated = false;
      for (auto const& auth: reply.saslSupportedMechs)
      {
          // See if we support the same mecahanism.
          // See: test/IntegrationConnectionMongoTest.cpp for examples.
          auto find = authenticators.find(auth);
          if (find != authenticators.end())
          {
              // We only try and authenticate with the first match.
              // The matches are tried in order provided by the server
              // as this is the servers preferred order.
              authenticated = true;
              find->second(stream, username, password, database);
              break;
          }
      }

      // If we did not find any authentication mechanisms
      // Then must throw as the server will not allow any actions.
      if (!authenticated)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Authenticate",
                                   "authenticteHandShake",
                                   "No compatable authentication mechanism found");
      }
  }

test/AuthenticateTest.cpp
  #include "gtest/gtest.h"

  #include "Authenticate.h"
  #include "Op_Msg.h"

  #include <sstream>

  namespace Auth = ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth;
  using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Authenticate;
  using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MessageId;
  using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Internal::getMessageId;

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateDriver)
  {
      // Should be default constructable.
      Auth::Driver    driver;

      EXPECT_EQ("ThorsAnvil::Mongo::Driver", driver.name);
      EXPECT_EQ("v2.0", driver.version);
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateOS)
  {
      // Should be default constructable.
      Auth::OS        os;

      EXPECT_NE("", os.type);
      if (os.name) {
          EXPECT_NE("", os.name.value());
      }
      if (os.architecture) {
          EXPECT_NE("", os.architecture.value());
      }
      if (os.version) {
          EXPECT_NE("", os.version.value());
      }
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateApplication)
  {
      Auth::Application   application("CreateApplication");

      EXPECT_EQ("CreateApplication", application.name);
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateClientIgnorePlatform)
{
      Auth::Client        client("CreateClient", {});

      EXPECT_EQ("CreateClient", client.application.name);

      EXPECT_EQ("ThorsAnvil::Mongo::Driver", client.driver.name);
      EXPECT_EQ("v2.0", client.driver.version);

      EXPECT_NE("", client.os.type);
      if (client.os.name) {
          EXPECT_NE("", client.os.name.value());
      }
      if (client.os.architecture) {
          EXPECT_NE("", client.os.architecture.value());
      }
      if (client.os.version) {
          EXPECT_NE("", client.os.version.value());
      }
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateClientNoPlatform)
  {
      Auth::Client        client("CreateClient", {});
      EXPECT_FALSE(client.platform);
  }
  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateClientEmptyPlatform)
  {
      Auth::Client        client("CreateClient", {""});
      EXPECT_FALSE(client.platform);
  }
  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CreateClientWithPlatform)
  {
      Auth::Client        client("CreateClient", {"Thor"});
      EXPECT_TRUE(client.platform);
      EXPECT_EQ("Thor", client.platform);
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, HandShake)
  {
      Auth::HandShake     handshake("user", "db", "application", {"Platform"}, {});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, handshake.hello);
      EXPECT_EQ("db.user", handshake.saslSupportedMechs);
      EXPECT_EQ("db", handshake.$db);
      // TODO: hostInfo

      EXPECT_EQ("application", handshake.client.application.name);

      EXPECT_EQ("ThorsAnvil::Mongo::Driver", handshake.client.driver.name);
      EXPECT_EQ("v2.0", handshake.client.driver.version);

      EXPECT_NE("", handshake.client.os.type);
      if (handshake.client.os.name) {
          EXPECT_NE("", handshake.client.os.name.value());
      }
      if (handshake.client.os.architecture) {
          EXPECT_NE("", handshake.client.os.architecture.value());
      }
      if (handshake.client.os.version) {
          EXPECT_NE("", handshake.client.os.version.value());
      }
      EXPECT_TRUE(handshake.client.platform);
      EXPECT_EQ("Platform", handshake.client.platform.value());

      EXPECT_EQ(0, handshake.compression.size());
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, HandShakeMultipleCompression)
  {
      Auth::HandShake     handshake("user", "db", "application", {"Platform"}, {"Snappy", "LZH"});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, handshake.hello);
      EXPECT_EQ("db.user", handshake.saslSupportedMechs);
      EXPECT_EQ("db", handshake.$db);
      // TODO: hostInfo

      ASSERT_EQ(2, handshake.compression.size());
      EXPECT_EQ("Snappy", handshake.compression[0]);
      EXPECT_EQ("LZH", handshake.compression[1]);
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, HandShakeFail)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;
      std::string mongoData("\x26\x00\x00\x00"      // Message Size
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Message ID
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Response ID
                            "\xdd\x07\x00\x00"      // OP_MSG
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Flags
                            "\x00"                  // Kind
                            "\x11\x00\x00\x00"      // BSON Size
                            "\x01"  "ok\x00"   "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // ok = 0
                            "\x00"s);               // BSON terminator

      MessageId replyId = getMessageId();
      char      update  = static_cast<char>(replyId);
      mongoData[8]      = update;

      std::stringstream mongoStream;
      mongoStream << mongoData;

      Authenticate    authenticate;
      auto action = [&](){authenticate.authenticte(mongoStream, "user", "password", "database", "appName", false);};
      EXPECT_THROW(
          action(),
          std::runtime_error
      );
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, HandShakeFailBadReply)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;
      std::string mongoData("\x26\x00\x00\x00"      // Message Size
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Message ID
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Response ID
                            "\xdd\x07\x00\x00"s);   // OP_MSG

      MessageId replyId = getMessageId();
      char      update  = static_cast<char>(replyId);
      mongoData[8]      = update;

      std::stringstream mongoStream;
      mongoStream << mongoData;

      Authenticate    authenticate;
      auto action = [&](){authenticate.authenticte(mongoStream, "user", "password", "database", "appName", false);};
      EXPECT_THROW(
          action(),
          std::runtime_error
      );
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, NoAuthMechanism)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;
      std::string mongoData("\x4A\x00\x00\x00"      // Message Size
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Message ID
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Response ID
                            "\xdd\x07\x00\x00"      // OP_MSG
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Flags
                            "\x00"                  // Kind
                            "\x35\x00\x00\x00"      // BSON Size                                4           =>  4
                            "\x01" "ok\x00" "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x3f"  //              1 + 3 + 8   => 12   16
                            "\x04" "saslSupportedMechs\x00"                     //              1 + 19      => 20   36
                                "\x10\x00\x00\x00"      // ARRAY Size                           4           =>  4   40
                                "\x02" "0\x00" "\x04\x00\x00\x00" "Bob\x00"     //              1 + 2 + 4+4 => 11   51
                                "\x00"                  // ARRAY Terminator                     1           =>  1   52
                            "\x00"s);                // BSON terminator                         1           =>  1   53 => 53 + 21 => 74

      MessageId replyId = getMessageId();
      char      update  = static_cast<char>(replyId);
      mongoData[8]      = update;

      std::stringstream mongoStream;
      mongoStream << mongoData;

      Authenticate    authenticate;
      auto action = [&](){authenticate.authenticte(mongoStream, "user", "password", "database", "appName", false);};
      EXPECT_THROW(
          action(),
          std::runtime_error
      );
  }

  TEST(AuthenticateTest, CallAuthMechanism)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;
      std::string mongoData("\x4A\x00\x00\x00"      // Message Size
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Message ID
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Response ID
                            "\xdd\x07\x00\x00"      // OP_MSG
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"      // Flags
                            "\x00"                  // Kind
                            "\x35\x00\x00\x00"      // BSON Size
                            "\x01" "ok\x00" "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x3f"
                            "\x04" "saslSupportedMechs\x00"␣
                                "\x10\x00\x00\x00"      // ARRAY Size
                                "\x02" "0\x00" "\x04\x00\x00\x00" "Bob\x00"
                                "\x00"                  // ARRAY Terminator
                            "\x00"s);               // BSON terminator

      MessageId replyId = getMessageId();
      char      update  = static_cast<char>(replyId);
      mongoData[8]      = update;

      std::stringstream mongoStream;
      mongoStream << mongoData;

      bool            called = false;
      Authenticate    authenticate;
      authenticate.addAuthenticator("Bob", [&](std::istream&,
                                               std::string const&,
                                               std::string const&,
                                               std::string const&)
                                           {
                                              called = true;
                                           });

      auto action = [&](){authenticate.authenticte(mongoStream, "user", "password", "database", "appName", false);};
      EXPECT_NO_THROW(action());
      EXPECT_TRUE(called);
  }

test/IntegrationConnectionMongoTest.cpp
  #include "gtest/gtest.h"

  #include "ConnectionMongo.h"
  #include "Authenticate.h"
  #include "AuthenticateScramSha.h"

  using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::ConnectionMongo;
  using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Authenticate;


  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, connectToMongoWithAuthenticator)
  {
      // This is a std::iostream that is implemented by a TCP/IP socket.
      ConnectionMongo     mongo("localhost", 27017);
      Authenticate        authenticate;

      authenticate.addAuthenticator("SCRAM-SHA-256", ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::ScramSha::authenticate);
      authenticate.authenticte(mongo, "test", "testPassword", "test", "IntegrationConnectionMongoTest::connectToMongo", false);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, connectToMongoWithAuthenticatorUsingSnappy)
  {
      // This is a std::iostream that is implemented by a TCP/IP socket.
      ConnectionMongo     mongo("localhost", 27017);
      Authenticate        authenticate;

      authenticate.addAuthenticator("SCRAM-SHA-256", ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Auth::ScramSha::authenticate);
      authenticate.authenticte(mongo, "test", "testPassword", "test", "IntegrationConnectionMongoTest::connectToMongo", true);
  }

